# I keep getting container status exit(0) when I try to start Tensorflow container on docker desktop

Tags: docker, tensorflow, containers, exit

It have never been started successfully.Can't see any log.status don't change and the starting up end instantly.
An ID is back actually when 'docker run',but can't be seen by command 'docker ps'.

Sure the hyper-v in on.I have no more knowledge about docker to do anything else.
I wish I can get a Tensorflow env quickly.

Comment: Containers will exit(0) when there is no foreground process.Seen like it  startd successfully then exits.I try plus a '-t' tag to command 'docker run',now I can see it running when 'docker ps'.I am going to use it and check if there are more questions.